# Uploading file with @type='file' in IE11

Tags: java, selenium

Below code works fine in Firefox, It uploads file without opening File Upload Window  but  in Internet Explorer 11
the file upload dialog is opened.

Assuming driver is a healthy WebDriver instance:

```
WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
fileInput.sendKeys("C:/path/to/file.jpg");
```

The idea is to directly send the absolute path to the file to an element which you would usually click at to get the modal window - that is `<input type='file' />` element.

Why file upload window is getting opened in IE 11 and how to fix this issue?

I need to test script on browser stack so It should not open file dialog window  while uploading file.

Answer (score 0):

IE always opens this dialog as it can't be disabled. However that doesn't mean this will break your tests. For some reason Selenium can enter the filepath into this dialog and still upload (don't ask me why it can enter the path in this dialog as I don't have a clue).

The problem is that there is a timeout on entering the path in this dialog. Selenium could be too quick and tries to enter the path before the dialog is properly opened. All you need to do is increase this timeout. For this there is an attribute you can add to your desired capabilities

```
{
'browserName': 'internet explorer',
'ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout': 10000
}
```

This will set a timeout of 10 seconds before entering the path.

Comment: Thanks RemcoW, There is no any other way to disabled os file dialog window for IE.This dialog box is disabled while uploading in firefox and chrome.